# Why does have_selector "#MyId" fail when match /id=\"MyId\"/ passes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a rails helper that generates a form

```
#helpers/my_helper.rb
def build_form 
  form_for object, url: object_path, method: :post do |f|
    html = f.text_input :field
    html += f.submit
    html.html_safe
  end
end
```

And tests for this helper

```
#spec/helpers/my_helper_spec.rb
describe MyHelper do
  it { expect( helper.my_helper ).to have_selector "form[action='#{objects_path}'][method='post']" } # PASSES
  it { expect( helper.my_helper ).to have_selector "#object_field" } #FAILS - but this should pass
  it { expect( helper.my_helper ).to match /id=\"object_field\"/ } # PASSES
end
```

I am still learning rspec, so this may be an obvious question.

Why are these tests failing when using `have_selector` on the inputs. And yet `have_selector` correctly passes on the form tag, and `match` passes on the input ID.

Comment: try have_selector :css, "#object_field"

Comment: Have you looked at the actual string your helper is returning?

Comment: Thanks @FrederickCheung, yes the string contains all the elements and the form renders as expected. I just can't get the matcher to behave as expected.

Comment: Can you post the string?

Answer (score 0):

How i understand, object_field is variable which contain id of element. If true, then try next:

```
 it { expect( helper.my_helper ).to have_selector "##{object_field}" }
```